# How to wait until a certain time to take a screenshot?

Tags: python, time, screenshot

I am using pyautogui to take a screenshot. The screenshot code is working fine, but I was wanting to wait until exactly 1:00 PM my time until it takes the screenshot. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the time variable of "1:00pm" is constant, I would recommend using windows scheduler and offboarding your python script on there. You can add a time variable to this and the script will essentially execute itself at a certain time. Please refer to [this website](https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/) for a setting up your script on windows scheduler.

Comment: How did you know OP was using Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can sleep your script equivalent seconds till screenshot time. You can tweak this to give a more accurate waiting time if needed.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from time import sleep

# specify schedule time here
SCREENSHOT_TIME = {'hour': 13, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0, 'microsecond': 0}

now = datetime.now()
seconds_till_time = (
      timedelta(hours=24)
      - (now - now.replace(**SCREENSHOT_TIME))
).seconds

sleep(seconds_till_time)

# do stuff
```